# Understanding assetic Bundle symfony 2

Tags: node.js, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, assetic

I am installing twitter bootstrap bundle in my symfony 2.3.1 project. I am following the documentation there but there's a point that I don't understand much and it looks is the reason for all my trouble:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        less:
            node:       /usr/local/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
```

What is this "node" and "node_paths" suppose to be?

Comment: I guess it's [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)'s path

Comment: I think they don't believe that someone using Bootstrap doesn't know Less and Node.js ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a path to [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and its modules

Comment: So I guess I need to install node.js first (why don't they say that in here? http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started#download-assets )

Comment: @Francesc I think because of http://lesscss.org/. But I agree, this is not a good practice not to provide full documentation.

Comment: Just for the sake of other people, (I am in RHEL OS) I did: yum -y install epel-release;yum -y install npm, npm install --global less, and then in the config file: node:       /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/lib/node_modules/]

Comment: You're not required to install node.js as stated in the docs. You can also rely on LessPHP instead.